# How to execute a php script after submit without ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, echo

I am actually using a PHP script that takes some time to execute.
It does echo strings every second, for let's say 1 min.
What I am trying to do is to "echo" these strings into my HTML page.
When I call my function inside my page, it works nicely, it executes when the page loads, and echo a string each second :

```html
<h1> Here is my func </h1>
<?php my_func();?>
```

But not I'd like to show this when I am sending a form (because I will use the form as parameters of my function).
So I tried something like this :

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
  <input name='param' value='param'type='text'/>
</form>
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url:'phpfileWithMyFunc.php',
    data: {
      param : param
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type:'post'
  )}.done(function (data){
    $('body').append(data);
  });
</script>
```

This one doesn't work at all, no idea why.
So I tried something else, with `$.post` :

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
  <input name='param' value='param'type='text'/>
</form>
<script>
  $('#form').submit(function () {
    $.post('phpfileWithMyFunc.php', { param: param }, function(result) {
      $('tbody').append(result);
    });
    return false;
   });
</script>
```

Finally, this one works, but my php file has to finish his execution (waiting 1 minute in my case), to have my results happened.

So I'm here to ask, is there any way to do as I was executing my PHP file "inside" my HTML file, so each time I echo a string it displays instantly on my HTML (every second in my case), instead of waiting for the end of my script?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The browser (where HTML is shown) is not connected to the server (where the PHP) executes like a driver is connected to an automobile. The connection is much more like a operating a drone - the operator is only _remotely_ connected to the drone. That means you cannot expect the switches on the controller to immediately affect the drone - the signals must be sent to the drone, and then the drone responds. This is your situation: the server (your PHP code) must send the signals (echo'd messages) to the browser. This can be done. Investigate the use of Web Sockets.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets for the server side || and check this for the client side: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really clear. I think i'm getting more how does php and javascript works together

Comment: You might want to check out https://socket.io/

Answer (score -1):

No, because php is interpreted in the server and you only get html in your browser.

Comment: php is an interpreted language.

Comment: Ok, but the answer is the same. You only can execute php in the server

Comment: There is a solution in the form of client server communication via web sockets.

Comment: I wanted to do like a "stream" between my server and my client, so each time the server echoes something, it shows into the client browser. Isn't that possible ?

Comment: Could you give me an example of a simple web socket in my case then please ?